# Issues recompiling/re-viewing in vim latex-suite

Tags: vim-latex

I've just installed the latex-suite plugin for vim and things are working well with one exception: recompiling my tex file after editing it doesn't show any of the new updates. For example, I can open up a pre-existing file, compile it, and view it without issues. But if I then add on some more text and recompile it again, zathura doesn't output the new text I've written. Vim isn't giving me any errors and I'm using `\ll` to (re)compile and `\lv` to view the output.

Comment: After making changes, are you saving the file before compiling? `\ll` compiles the last saved version of the tex file, not the tex file as it currently is in vim.

Comment: Ah, that was what I was forgetting to do. Thank you very much for solving my simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

vim-latex has the command `\ll` to compile `tex` files but this command does not save the open `tex` file and so when `\ll` starts the compilation it is of the last-saved version of the `tex` file.  In order to compile the latest version, it is necessary to save before compilation i.e. `:w<CR> \ll`.

To reduce this to a single command, I use `map <Leader>t :w<CR><bar><Leader>ll` in my `vimrc` (though it could more appropriately be placed somewhere to only activate with `tex` files).

Such write and compile mappings are discussed in [How do I make vim-latex compile correctly without having to save?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740609) and [How can I tell vim to compile a document on save?](https://superuser.com/q/269562) on other SE sites.